# Error en el codigo al actualizar los paquetes en pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, dart

Una vez actualizados los paquetes de pubspec.yaml a una nueva version, el codigo marca error, en firestore y en document, que se podría hacer para corregir estos errores. Es un proyecto en Dart usando Flutter.
Lo que se cree es que basicamente solo es de refactorizar el codigo usando el paquete actualizado, Se presenta a continuacion un fragmento de codigo que presenta el error de la clase para PDF, ahora se esta intentando actualizar tambien el codigo pero marca rror desde return Container

Por ejemplo

```
 final pdf = pw.Document();

  pdf.addPage(pw.Page(
      pageFormat:
          PdfPageFormat.letter.copyWith(marginBottom: 1.5 * PdfPageFormat.cm),
      build: (pw.Context context) {
        return pw.Center(
          child: pw.Text("H"),
        ); 
       // if (context.pageNumber == 1) {
         // return null;
        //}
        return Container(  //Desde aqui marca error
            pw.Alignment: pw.Alignment.centerRight,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3.0 * PdfPageFormat.mm),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3.0 * PdfPageFormat.mm),
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                border:
                    pw.BoxBorder(bottom: true, width: 0.5, color: PdfColors.grey)),
            child: pw.Text('Portable Document Format',
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .defaultTextStyle
                    .copyWith(color: PdfColors.grey)));
},
```

Comment: Tienes una imagen del error o la descripción del error?

Comment: @ Felipe Vergara   Se ha agregado un fragmento de codigo como ejmplo del error

Comment: @ FelipeVergara Se ha agregado un fragmento de codigo como ejmplo del error